# why does permissions in one database affect another with same schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have database A and B and user app_user. They both have the schema public. I granted read access to database A for app_user. When my application runs, it complains that "relation does not exist". When I login as that user into db A, I can indeed select from tables. Next I deleted the database B entirely and now my application runs.... ???? This is a rails app running on a postgres DB by the way. The rails app is pointing to db A based on config.

Comment: Try it from a console using just ActiveRecord if you can, try to eliminate Rails from the suspect list.

Answer (score 0):

Roles are cluster-global.  This leads to a number of things that can happen.  In general in troubleshooting this you should be familiar with pgAdmin or psql.  The former lets you see the permissions on db objects in the GUI.  For the latter use `\z relation` to see the grants.

There are two likely culprets:

1. Grants to `PUBLIC` which is not a role but allows access to any authenticated user.
2. Identical grants in two databases to the same role.  If you drop the first database, the role will not be dropped and so your second database will still work.  This is behavior as designed.